# Apache kafka separate producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

I have multiple servers from where the messages will be produced, and I need broker and consumer at one server.
If I have both producer and consumer running on same server then it works fine, but not sure what changes need to be done to keep producers separate. I don't want any dependency of zookeeper and kafka servers at producer servers as there are many and they will increase. 
I tried with changing bootstrap server to the broker/consumer server like 192.168.0.1:9092 while setting up KafkaProducer but still not able to generate messages. Not sure what am I missing, please help me out here.

**producer.props**

```
bootstrap.servers=192.168.0.1:9092
acks=all
retries=0
batch.size=16384
auto.commit.interval.ms=1000
linger.ms=0
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
block.on.buffer.full=true
```

**Producer code**

```
public class Producer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // set up the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
        System.out.println("1");
        try (InputStream props = Resources.getResource("producer.props").openStream()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(props);
            producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

                // send lots of messages
                System.out.println("bedore send");
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                            "fast-messages",
                            String.format("{\"type\":\"marker\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(
                            "summary-markers",
                            String.format("{\"type\":\"other\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));
                    producer.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent msg number " + i);
            }
            System.out.println("fdone");
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            System.out.printf("%s", throwable.getStackTrace());
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you should not flush the producer for every single message, but it's not really clear if/what errors you're getting... You can setup Slf4j to see internal producer logs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the problem you are running into, but it seems that clarity of information is not there. I will try and answer it theoretically. 
Producers and consumers are both clients of Kafka brokers. So, as far as brokers are configured in producers properly, the messages are sent to the kafka servers without any issue. Similar is the case with Consumers. Typically, the kafka cluster (brokers) is separately created to handle the messages. Producers and consumers are not needed to run Kafka servers. So, your clients can be running anywhere with the configuration of brokers within them. There is no dependency between producer & consumer. They are independent programs that do the job of publishing messages to Kafka cluster (producers) and receiving messages from kafka cluster (consumers). Producers are not dependent on Zookeeper nodes. Zookeeper is used as dependency by Kafka servers for metadata management. Your statement " any dependency of zookeeper and kafka servers at producer servers" is not justified as Producers will use the broker configuration to connect to the kafka servers (bootstrapping).

Comment: Yes, that is correct but I am not able to push my message to broker if they are at separate servers though I have set the properties for bootstrap server properly

Comment: You need to put the configuration here. Just saying that you have put properly will not help anyone to understand what you have done. Paste the code having broker information as well. As a preliminary test, you can first try connecting producer server to kafka server (brokers) to see if there is some network issue.